# Parsing a very complex json response in dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to load a json file from a server response and parsing it in flutter, the model i create is working for all the other fields but i'm in trouble with this class

this is a part of the JSON response:

```
    "episodes": {
    "1": [
      {
        "id": "63",
        "episode_num": 1,
        "title": "Some Name",
        "container_extension": "mp4",
        "info": {
          "director": "",
          "plot": "",
          "cast": "",
          "rating": "",
          "releasedate": "",
          "movie_image": "",
          "genre": "",
          "duration_secs": 6495,
          "duration": "01:48:15"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

in this case the entry under episodes is just one but this will represents a season and all the episode inside it, so under episodes many of this entry (undefined number during coding) can be present

At this time, using online json to dart converter tools i can be able to retrive just this one entry but if a response have more than 1 season i can't see it.

There is any way to handle this?

EDIT:
Solved using a for cicle with max value = `(json['episodes'].length + 1)`.
For the info stored inside each 'episodes' value i can use

```
json['episodes']['$i']
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid JSON is *always* convertible to a Dart data structure.  But what you may be asking is "can I get nested objects from this?", and that just depends on how hard you want to work.  Some JSON-to-Dart tools are better than others and some JSON values are impossible for any automated tool to make sense of.  Only real answer is: "it depends".